Contraction of an inclusion with respect to Kobayshi hyperbolic metric
Suppose that $X = \mathbb{C}^n - \Delta_X$ and $Y = \mathbb{C}^n - \Delta_Y$, where $\Delta_X$ and $\Delta_Y$ are unions of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\Delta_Y \subset \Delta_X$, $\Delta_Y$ contains $n(n + 3)/2$ hyperplanes and $\Delta_X \setminus \Delta_Y$ consists of at least $n$ hyperplanes.
Suppose that both $X$ and $Y$ are Kobayashi hyperbolic. Then the inclusion map $i \colon X \to Y$ is 1-Lipschitz with respect to the Kobayashi metrics on $X$ and $Y$, i.e., for each $v \in T_pX$, we have $\|v\|_Y/\|v\|_X \leq 1$.
Is it true that $\|v\|_Y/\|v\|_X$ is strictly less than 1?
